# Boundary of an infinite union of hyperplanes

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $A(x)$ be a matrix-valued function:
$$A(x) = (a_{ij}(x))_{1\leq i, j\leq n}:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\, n\geq 2.$$
where the scalar entries $a_{ij}(x)$ are smooth and $a_{ij}(x)\in[0,M].$ Define the map:
\begin{align}B(x,\mathbf{y}) = A(x)\mathbf{y}:D\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n\\
D = [0,\infty)\times D_{n-1}
\end{align}
where $D_{n-1}$ is:
$$D_{n-1} = \{\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R^n\vert\, \|\mathbf{y}\|_1=1, \mathbf{y}_i\geq 0}\}$$
i.e., the part in the first quadrant of the unit ball in $L_1$ norm. My question is if this $B$ maps boundaries of its domain to boundaries in the image. That is, is the following implication true:
$$\mathbf{y} = (0,y_2,y_3,...y_n)\in D_{n-1}\implies B(x,\mathbf{y}) \in\partial(B(D)) $$
My hunch is that this is true since the map is linear in $\mathbf{y}$, but I cannot quite formalize this intuition.

Comment: It fails with n=1 so I don't see why it should be true for other cases

Comment: well the context of the problem comes from viewing $B(x,\mathbf{y})$ as a weighted average of columns of $A(x),$ so only $n\geq 2$ is being considered. When $n = 1$, $D_0$ actually cannot be defined.

Comment: I'm writing you a counterexample in dimension 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
1+\cos(x) & 4-\cos(x)\\
1+\sin(x) & 1+\sin(x)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a smooth matrix with nonnegative entries bounded by 5. Take $x=0$, $y=(1,0)$ and you get $(2,1)$ that is in the interior of the image of the operator.
To see this, notice that
$$v_1(x) := A(x) \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}
1+\cos(x) \\
1+\sin(x) 
\end{pmatrix},
\qquad
v_2(x) := A(x) \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}
4-\cos(x) \\
1+\sin(x) 
\end{pmatrix},
 $$
and that
$$B(D) = \cup_{x\ge 0} conv(\{v_1(x),v_2(x)\}) =
\cup_{x\ge 0} \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
z \\
1+\sin(x) 
\end{pmatrix}
: 
1+\cos(x)\le z\le 4-\cos(x)
\right\}.
$$
If you now take $\pi/2\le x\le 3\pi/2$, you see that $1+\sin(x)$ spans the segment $[0,2]$ and that $1+\cos(x)\le 1\le 4\le 4-\cos(x)$, so the rectangule $[1,4]\times[0,2]$ is inside $B(D)$ and the point $(2,1)$ is in its interior part.

Comment: thanks this works. Although the particular $A$ I am working with has more restrictive properties like PSD, column stochastic etc. So this means if my claim is correct for my $A$, there needs to be a more tailored proof, not some general result like I hoped. All kinds of simulations suggested the claim holds for that $A.$